# Change the destination folder of a Google Form upload file

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm totally new here, and trying to learn about Google Apps Script.

I'd say that my objetive is pretty simple: I just want to specify a destination folder for the upload files of a Google Form. I've found ways to do something similar, but it creates a new folder for every new file, while my goal is to use an already existing folder in Google Drive.

Thanks!